# Generating HMAC

Tags: java, junit, base64

I had been working on several projects that required Header Message Authentication Codes to be generated when brokering files with 3rd parties like Netflix.

Unfortunately on older systems like Windows Server 2003, Solaris and early versions of RHEL there was no easy way to generate HMACs which could be Base encoded.

So I created this Java application to do what I needed.

I have come from a C++ background so would appreciate some review to my Java code.

Particularly interested in people's opinions of how I've balanced the logic between Main and other classes.

[HMAC_BASE on github](https://github.com/loosebruce/HMAC_BASE)

**Main.java**

```
/**
 * 
 */
package com;



import helper.Base;
import helper.HMAC;
import helper.IOHandler;
import helper.Posix;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import org.apache.commons.cli.CommandLine;
import org.apache.commons.cli.ParseException;
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;



/**
 * @author Bruce Taylor
 * 
 */
public class Main
{

    // one instantiation of log4j per class
    private static Logger log = Logger.getLogger(Main.class.getName());
    private static CommandLine cl;
    private static IOHandler io = new IOHandler();;

    /*
     * Current methods
     */
    private static enum methods
    {
        base, hmac_base
    }

    /*
     * Sets the loglevel
     */
    public static void setLogLevel()
    {
        if (cl.hasOption("debug"))
        {
            log.info("Debugging has been enabled.");
            log.setLevel(Level.DEBUG);
        }
        else
            log.setLevel(Level.OFF);

    }

    /*
     * Perform HMAC operation
     */
    public static byte[] doHMAC(String str) throws InvalidKeyException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidAlgorithmParameterException, UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        log.info("Input string for HMAC : " + str);
        if (cl.hasOption("hash") && cl.hasOption("key"))
        {
            String hashKey = cl.getOptionValue("key");
            String hashMethod = cl.getOptionValue("hash");
            log.info("Hashing algorithm being used is : " + hashMethod);
            log.info("Secret key is : " + hashKey);

            HMAC hmac = new HMAC(hashKey.getBytes(), hashMethod);
            hmac.generateHash(str);
            return hmac.getHash();
        }
        else
        {
            if (cl.hasOption("hash"))
            {
                log.error("No key given for HMAC.");
                System.exit(-1);
            }
            if (cl.hasOption("key"))
            {
                log.error("No hashing algorithm given for HMAC.");
                System.exit(-1);
            }

        }
        return null;

    }

    /*
     * @param str Perform Base operation
     */
    public static byte[] doBase(byte[] bs) throws UnsupportedEncodingException
    {
        log.info("Input string for Base : " + bs);

        if (cl.hasOption("encode"))
        {
            String baseMethod = cl.getOptionValue("encode");
            log.info("Doing encode in " + baseMethod);
            if (Base.isBaseMethodValid(baseMethod) == true)
                return Base.encode(bs, baseMethod);
            else
                throw new UnsupportedEncodingException("Unsupported encoder : " + baseMethod);

        }
        else if (cl.hasOption("decode"))
        {
            String baseMethod = cl.getOptionValue("encode");
            log.info("Doing decode");
            if (Base.isBaseMethodValid(baseMethod) == true)
                return Base.decode(bs, baseMethod);
            else
                throw new UnsupportedEncodingException("Unsupported encoder : " + baseMethod);
        }
        else if (cl.hasOption("decode") && cl.hasOption("encode"))
        {
            log.error("Both encode and decode methods have been called, remove one method.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        else
        {
            log.error("No base operation specified.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        return null;
    }

    /*
     * Retrieves input arg and passes it to IOHandler
     */
    public static String handleInput() throws IOException
    {
        log.info("Checking input.");

        if (cl.hasOption("input"))
        {
            String input = cl.getOptionValue("input");
            log.info("An input of : " + input + " was specified.");

            io.interpretInput(input);

            // user wants to remove whitespace from input
            if (cl.hasOption("cleanseWs"))
                io.cleanseWhiteSpace();
            // user wants to remove new lines from input
            if (cl.hasOption("cleanseNl"))
                io.cleanseNewLine();
            // user wants to remove characters from input using custom regex
            if (cl.hasOption("cleanse"))
                io.cleansePattern(cl.getOptionValue("cleanse"));

        }
        else
        {
            log.error("No input specified, exiting.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }
        log.info("Final input is : " + io.getString());
        return io.getString();
    }

    /*
     * Produces output either to the command line or to a specified file
     * @param output
     */
    public static void handleOutput(byte[] output) throws IOException
    {
        log.info("Preparing output");

        if (cl.hasOption("file"))
        {
            String filename = cl.getOptionValue("file");
            log.info("Value to be written to file : " + filename);
            io.outputToFile(filename, output);
        }
        else
        {
            log.info("Outputting using standard output.");
            System.out.println(new String(output, "UTF-8"));
        }
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        try
        {
            // initialise Posix object and parse arguments from command line
            cl = new Posix(args).parseArgs();

            // set loglevel depending on presence of -debug argument
            setLogLevel();

            log.info("Parsing command line arguments.");
            // check mimimum arguments given
            if (cl.getOptions().length > 1)
            {
                // can't use string switch in Java 1.6

                // do base only
                if (cl.hasOption("base"))
                {
                    try
                    {
                        log.info("A BASE operation will only be performed in this execution.");
                        byte[] output = doBase(handleInput().getBytes());
                        log.info("Final output is : " + new String(output, "UTF-8"));
                        handleOutput(output);
                    }
                    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage() + ", only the following BASE encoding methods " + java.util.Arrays.asList(Base.validBaseMethods.values()) + " are currently accepted.");
                        System.exit(-1);
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage() + ", please ensure file and current working directory is writable.");
                        System.exit(-1);
                    }

                }
                // do hmac and base
                else if (cl.hasOption("hmac_base"))
                {
                    log.info("Both HMAC and BASE operations will be performed in this execution.");

                    try
                    {
                        byte[] output = doBase(doHMAC(handleInput()));
                        log.info("Final output is : " + new String(output, "UTF-8"));
                        handleOutput(output);
                    }
                    catch (InvalidKeyException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage() + ", the HMAC key provided is invalid.");
                        System.exit(-1);
                    }
                    catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage() + ", this really shouldn't come up as an error message.");
                        System.exit(-1);
                    }
                    catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage() + ", only the following HMAC methods " + java.util.Arrays.asList(HMAC.validHmacMethods.values()) + " are accepted.");
                        System.exit(-1);
                    }
                    catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage() + ", only the following BASE encoding methods " + java.util.Arrays.asList(Base.validBaseMethods.values()) + " are currently accepted.");
                        System.exit(-1);
                    }
                    catch (IOException e)
                    {
                        System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage() + ", please ensure file and current working directory is writable.");
                        System.exit(-1);
                    }
                }
                // default
                else
                {
                    log.error("No operation method specific. Expected either \"hmac_base\" or \"base\" .");
                    System.exit(-1);
                    // TODO
                }

            }
            else
            {
                log.error("The minimum amount of arguments required were not given. Expected " + methods.values());
                System.exit(-1);
            }

        }

        // end of posix try block
        catch (ParseException e)
        {
            // occurs with invalid posix options given
            System.out.println(e.getLocalizedMessage() + ", please check the user manual for all accepted command arguments.");
            System.exit(-1);
        }

    }
}

// the spice must flow
```

P.s. my jUnit tests are foobar currently, so would appreciate some guidance on how to properly pass POSIX arguments iteratively to Main from a test case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Code

To summarise the issues I see below, I'd suggest using less `static`
methods/classes because it makes testing way harder and in general looks
unnecessary in most places except maybe the helper stuff.  I'd also take
a look at common libraries, so you don't have to rewrite e.g. file
reading and input cleaning.  Obvious candidates would be Guava, Apache
Commons and so on.

I'm not too happy with the different classes.  `CommandOptions` is good,
because you set up the command line options once there.  But then, you
actually handle them in `Main`.  I'd move the checks into
`CommandOptions`, then have regular methods, `getHash`, `getKey`, which
do the logic you currently have in `doHMAC` and `doBase`.

The helper classes look okay I guess, but it's still confusing that your
helpers depend on the main classes `Main` and `CommandOptions` and not
the other way round.

- You strive for compatibility with Java 1.6, so I'm to skip
  recommendations for newer language features; just going to say that
  the exception handling can be a bit shorter if you do the dispatching
  yourself, i.e. catch `Exception`, print `.getLocalizedMessage` and
  then check the type yourself.  IMO having less code for that is
  preferable.
- The indentation isn't optimal; you can get rid of some levels of
  indentation by exiting early, moving blocks into methods, etc.
  E.g. in the `main` method, you can move the check for any arguments
  before the rest and then exit if there aren't any arguments.  Same in
  `Base.java:148`.
- Lots of (empty) comments which don't add any information.  E.g. `Sets
  the loglevel` is something I can already see from the method name
  `setLoglevel`.
- The actual functionality is very tightly coupled with option parsing
  and error handling by `System.exit`.  It would be better to move
  options in a separate part, so that methods like `doHMAC` are
  "obviously correct" instead of having to wade through the
  logging/option handling parts.
- Also, `System.exit` directly in such a method is very harsh.  I'd
  rather propagate an exception so that the method is usable from other
  places as well, like you already do in the `main` method.  That way,
  parts of the application could also be reused as a library.
- `if (foo == true)` or `if (foo == false)` is not necessary, just use
  `if (foo)` (and similar cases as well).
- Enumerations usually use upper case constants (`methods` in
  `Main.java`) and the enumeration itself should follow regular class
  naming.
- `doHMAC`, `doBase` have a `return null` that looks like it's either
  not executed or wrong anyway.
- The staticness of `Main.java` is detrimental to the ease of testing
  that class.  First steps to change that would probably be using
  parameters (either for the methods, or the class/constructor) instead
  of static members.
- `Base.java:74` is a bug I think; after lower casing you'll never match
  it with `Base32`.  Also, what happens if the method is suddenly `foo`?
  Also, again way too much `static`.
- `HMAC.java:75`, why `new Hex();`?  That's not used anywhere.

As an example for "too much code",`Posix.java:49`, the whole method can
just be `return new PosixParser().parse(comOptions, args);` with no loss
of functionality.

Some of these things can also be discovered by automatic checkers like
CheckStyle, PMD and so on.  Some will also warn about package
dependencies, so it might be useful to run those on the project as well.

## Tests

As you already saw passing arguments via a `private static` member like
`CommandLine` is not the best way to do that.  Although I'm pretty sure
there are mocking libraries to circumvent the restrictions.

So what you can do immediately is to make `Main` a regular, non-`static`
class, with `cl` and `io` either passed in via constructor arguments, or
available via `getCommandLine`, etc.  In you test case you'd instantiate
the application each time, set command line arguments and then call
whatever function you want.  For that it would also be advisable to move
logic out of the `main` method, or you're okay with not testing that
part.

## Packaging

- Usually you'd use reverse domain names for packages.  There's also a
  quasi standard project layout used by Maven.  In any case `com` and
  `helper` as top-level package names aren't great.
- It would be good to have a Maven or ant file to build it without an
  IDE.  I haven't yet compiled it for that exact reason.
- The `README.md` has a section `Installation`, but if you really want
  people to use it, they shouldn't have to know how to build a runnable
  JAR file from scratch.  That ties in with the point above:  provide
  either/and a Makefile, Maven build file and ant build file and *then*
  also put some paragraphs into `Installation` on how to exactly invoke
  commands to build the application (and run tests).  E.g. some along
  the lines of "Invoke 'mvn compile' to create 'build/hmac.jar'."  Maybe
  even have an installation routine to install a small wrapper script to
  call that jar, "Invoke 'mvn install PREFIX=/usr/local' to install the
  'hmac' script on your machine."  Obviously there's a lot more work
  there, so you can just start of with some build instructions first.

Hope that helps!  Also take it with a grain of salt, I'm biased towards
Spring, so that shows I guess.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time for reviewing my code. I will do some refactoring on it this week. Perhaps I should do some Java training or certification? Although I do feel that I can take what I know from C into Java, it might not be to conventions but I can learn those on the way. Many thanks!

Comment: Eh, it looks good enough I think; since you already enough to produce working code I doubt the value of certification, but YMMV.  If you maybe take a look at a Java style guide, or so maybe that's helpful; if you care about testing then using dependency injection and non-`static` methods just makes your life easier, since your code is already doing what it should.